# My text box always compare with '0' whatever number i enter

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, sqlite

I was trying to set a range of numbers at text box (CHWV.text) which will able to update my database base on my if else condition.
I tried to key into the text box from 0 to 100. then use int.TryParse to convert the text box value into an integer.
However, CHWTemp always get 0 whatever numbers i try enter.

The codes run perfectly,but i cannot get the CHWTemp i wanted after entering into the text box.
I not sure Is there anything i missed out?

```
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

        int CHWTemp;

        int.TryParse(CHWV.Text,out CHWTemp);

        try

        {
            sqlite_conn.Open();  

            if (CHWTemp >= 0 && CHWTemp <= 10)
                {
                    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 25 where id=12");
                    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 11 && CHWTemp <= 20)
                {
                    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 24 Where id=12");
                    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 21 && CHWTemp <= 40)
                {
                    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 23 where id=12");
                    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 41 && CHWTemp <= 60)
                {
                    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 22 where id=12");
                    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 61 && CHWTemp <= 80)
                {
                    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 21 where id=12");
                    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 81 && CHWTemp <= 100)
                {
                    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 20 where id=12");
                    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            sqlite_conn.Close();
        }
        catch ()
        {
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `TryParse` probably fails. see it's return value. if it does, check exactly what is the value of `CHWV.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using the value of CHWTemp please check the return value of int.TryParse(CHWV.Text,out CHWTemp); If you are getting false than the conversion is not happening from string to int.

```
bool ifSuccess = int.TryParse(CHWV.Text,out CHWTemp);
```

if the value of ifSuccess is true then conversion from string to int is done but if the value of CHWV.Text is not convertible to int you will get false in return and the value of CHWTemp will be 0.

Just check that your getting the correct string from the text box. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, i know where my problem is. i cleared my textbox which leave the textbox empty. thus it always return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code seems good to me. To be safe, I created [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yT5I0X), in which I removed all sql related stuff, and replaced them with Console.WriteLine's.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int CHWTemp;
        String inputStr = "17";
        int.TryParse(inputStr,out CHWTemp);


            if (CHWTemp >= 0 && CHWTemp <= 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 25 where id=12");
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 11 && CHWTemp <= 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 24 Where id=12");
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 21 && CHWTemp <= 40)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 23 where id=12");
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 41 && CHWTemp <= 60)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 22 where id=12");
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 61 && CHWTemp <= 80)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 21 where id=12");
                }
                else if (CHWTemp >= 81 && CHWTemp <= 100)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UPDATE Temperature SET Temp = 20 where id=12");
                }

    }
}
```

As you can see, it works just fine. So, it is easy to say, parsing part works as expected. Therefore I think the point of failure looks like how you get the string from your text field.

So, my suggestion for you is to make sure that CHWV.Text returns a string representation of the number you enter.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, i know where my problem is. i cleared my textbox which leave the textbox empty. thus it always return 0.